# Apriori Algo shows 'FALSE' rather than 'TRUE"

Tags: r, apriori

Here's my code:

```
 #install and load libraries
library(arules)
library(arulesViz)
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)
library(knitr)
library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)

#read .csv file
market <- read.csv(file.choose(),header=T, colClasses = "factor")
market <- market[complete.cases(market), ]

str(market)

rules <- apriori(market, parameter = list(supp=0.1, conf=0.8))
inspect(rules[1:10])
```

Here's a sample of the result:

```
    lhs                      rhs                 support confidence  coverage     lift count
[1]  {Butter=FALSE,                                                                          
      Sugar=FALSE,                                                                           
      Yogurt=FALSE,                                                                          
      chocolate=FALSE}     => {Onion=FALSE}     0.1291291  0.8012422 0.1611612 1.343022   129
[2]  {Butter=FALSE,                                                                          
      Kidney.Beans=FALSE,                                                                    
      Yogurt=FALSE,                                                                          
      chocolate=FALSE}     => {Milk=FALSE}      0.1361361  0.8047337 0.1691692 1.353416   136
```

So as you can see the results shows 'FALSE'. Question is how can I make it true instead?

Answer (score 0):

Variables are translated to items depending on the data type. Here are some details from the manual page for transactions (see `? transactions`):

- **Factors:** Columns with nominal values (i.e., factor, ordered) are translated into a series of binary items (one for each level constructed as  ⁠variable name = level⁠).
- **Logical variables:** A logical variable describing a person could be tall indicating if the person is tall using the values TRUE and FALSE. The fact that the person is tall would be encoded in the transaction containing the item tall while not tall persons would not have this item. Therefore, for logical variables, the TRUE value is converted into an item with the name of the variable and for the FALSE values, no item is created.

Since you read the data as factors with levels TRUE and FALSE, you get also items for the level FALSE. You can read them in as `logical` or convert the appropriate columns in the data frame using `as.logical()` before you call apriori. Have a look at the examples in `? transactions`. This should help you understand this conversion better.